# Is identity map one to one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading a chapter of compactness in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed. Actually, identity map has been involved in and I've captured its definition:

---

### Equivalent Metrics

As a last topic related to both compactness and uniform continuity, we discuss several notions of equivalence for metrics (and norms). Throughout, we will suppose that $d$  and $\rho$ are two metrics on the same set $M$. We will write $i:(M,d)\to(M,\rho)$ as the identity map and $i^{-1}:(M,\rho)\to(M,d)$ as its inverse (also the identity map, but in the other direction).

---

So is identity map one to one and onto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-1 means $f(a) = f(b)$ only if $a=b$. Clearly, for identity map this holds.

onto means for each $a \in M$ there is a $b \in M$ such that $f(b) = a$, which is trivially true for the identity map, let $b = a$.